# Resolving datatype missmatch between redshift tables and parquet files on S3 exported from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, parquet

So we have a lot of lambda's running every hour, they query data from APIs, transform the json responses into dataframe, and insert the dataframes with `method='multi'` for bulk inserts.

But all these lambas are putting alot of pressure on our single node redshift cluster (Yes we're small, increasing nodes isnt an option for now). Whenever the lambdas insert data into our cluster, the CPU usage goes to 100% which causes other jobs to timeout.

To speed up the inserts i was testing awswrangler's redshift COPY.

1. Turn json responses to dataframe
2. Export dataframe to parquet using wr.s3.to_parquet()
3. use wr.redshift.copy() to append parquet to redshift table

To test the UNLOAD and COPY using awswrangler

1. Captured a dataframe of a few rows from a sample table using `wr.redshift.unload()`
2. Loading the dataframe into a similar schema test table using `wr.redshift.copy()`

COPY fails, throwing `Spectrum Scan Error: <s3path> has an incompatible Parquet schema for column`:

- TIMESTAMP columns are converted to CHAR types
- INT2 columns are converted to INT64

I was expecting the exported dataframe to have similar schema as the table, or the copy to resolve datatype mismatch.

UNLOAD call:

```
test_df = wr.redshift.unload(
    sql=f"SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table_name};",
    path="s3://bucket-name/copy_test/",
    keep_files=False,
    con=rs_con
)
```

COPY CALL

```
wr.redshift.copy(
    df=test_df,
    table=table_name,
    schema=schema,
    keep_files=False,
    path='s3://bucket-name/copy_test/',
    use_column_names=True,
    index=False,
    con=rs_con
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the schema of the Parquet files matches the schema of the target Redshift table, by specifying the correct data types for the columns when writing the Parquet files using `wr.s3.to_parquet()`, or by using the schema parameter to specify the target Redshift table schema when calling `wr.redshift.copy()`.

You can also use the `data_conversion_params` parameter of `wr.redshift.copy()` to specify how data type conversions should be handled during the COPY operation. This can be useful if you need to perform data type conversions that are not supported by default when loading data from Parquet files into Redshift.

Comment: what value does the `data_conversion_params` accept? coz i cant find any documentation for it in official docs.

Also i should mention the schema argument is already given to the `copy()` call. But `schema` and `table` params are only used to identify target table.

let me add the calls to my question.